# Google analytics website - install attribution on PC

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for a way to track installation (or actually launches) of a PC game and correlate them with information from my website google analytics (such as traffic source, landing url, etc).

I'd like to track conversion rates. I can add HTTP/API calls from my desktop application.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) to record your game goals and send them as hits to Google Analytics. You can practise with the [hit builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).

Remember [Google Analytics Collection Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas?hl=en) in order to make sure you collect everything.

Comment: Thanks, I tested that. Now, how can I see where these conversions came from previously? (urls that they visited in the website before the event)?

Comment: Check user ID in order to unify all the data https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#uid

Comment: Hmm, but how do I get the user/client ID submittend by the app to match the one sent by the browser hit when they enter the website?